# Installation of a Spring Boot application as an init.d service in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, ubuntu-14.04, init.d

I've generated a Spring Boot app. with maven, moved the jar into

```
/var/licence/licence-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Then

```
sudo ln -s /var/licence/licence-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /etc/init.d/licence
```

But when I type

```
lopes@localhost:/var/licence$ service licence start
licence: unrecognized service
```

These are the attributes of `/etc/init.d/licence`

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   46 Mar 27 18:17 licence -> /var/licence/licence-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

This is my pom.xml:

....

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>   
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>            
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
...
```

Comment: Did you create an executable jar as explained in the reference guide?

Comment: yes, I created an executable jar as explained in the reference guid

Comment: Which boot version are you using and have you checked the logs? As mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-initd-service)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the old-fashioned `/etc/init.d` you'd better use a systemd unit file. systemd is the `init` system used by most Linux distros, and integrating your service is both easier (see below) and more powerful because you get for free supervisioning, logging facilities, dependency management on other services and so on.

Regarding an example for your service, you first need to put a `license.service` in the directory `/etc/systemd/system` with contents like:

```init
[Unit]
Description=License service by MyCorp

[Service]
ExecStart=/var/licence/licence-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
User=myuser
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

and then run these commands:

```
#>systemctl daemon-reload
#>systemctl enable license
#>systemctl start license
```

Note that SpringBoot can create a executable JAR (ie a JAR that starts with a shell script) so you don't need to call `java` explicitely. See the [spring.io documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-systemd-service) for how to customize.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `java -jar` part as the `jar` should be the executable (script) as explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-systemd-service).

Comment: Thanks. Updated the answer

Answer (score 5):

As I know /etc/init.d stores only script files. 
You should put there script file, where you describe how to start/stop your service. Below I wrote sample script save it as `/etc/init.d/license` and you can start/stop your service like this
`sudo service license start`

sample scriptdetail in this [resource](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/linux-java-service-wrapper-example)

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE_NAME=License
PATH_TO_JAR=/var/licence/licence-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/License.pid

case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null & 
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    stop)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    restart)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
            nohup java -jar $PATH_TO_JAR /tmp 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null &
                        echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: An executable Spring Boot jar is a script as explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-initd-service).